# Mac App Store - Copy Protection, or not, or what?

Tags: macos, app-store, copy-protection

the license agreement for the Mac Developer Program explicitly states that I am not to implement my own copy protection process in my Mac app.

Yet, in the developer documentation, Apple also says this:

> You can add receipt validation code to
>   your application to prevent
>   unauthorized copies of your
>   application from running.

I am confused here. Does the Mac App Store provide any form of built-in copy protection for Mac apps? The above statement from Apple would seem to indicate that it does not.

The statement suggests that if I do not implement these receipt checks, then unauthorised copies of my Mac App CAN run on other Macs.

I'm not allowed to implement (or rather, keep an existing) copy protection, but I am expected to verify receipts manually, using various fragments of code and pseudo-code provided by Apple, simply to provide the most basic level of protection. Is this interpretation correct?

Is this a miscommunication from Apple, or is this really how things are done?

Ref: http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/documents/validating.html

Thanks.

(Please note that I'm not after a debate on the philosophy of copy-protection or the merits of Apple's approach. Rather, I'm just interested in the technical requirements for getting a Mac app on to the App Store.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. It's their way or the highway.

Comment: So basically, I have to remove my existing (working) copy protection, and replace it with a system designed around validating a single receipt file, doing all the obfuscation and internal checking that a copy protection system requires?  Wow, that's... argh.

Comment: Yup. It's definitely laughable.

Comment: The best part is that following their instructions for validating the receipt requires a fairly high level of cryptography expertise.  Fortunately, there is an open source project starting up: https://github.com/roddi/ValidateStoreReceipt

Comment: Unfortunately, using a free software library to do the receipt check means that crackers can easily bypass the protection (and even automate the process). It’s a nice point of reference, though.

Comment: Crackers will almost never pay for software. If they can crack your app, that means they like it. They will tell others to buy it. Only worry about the people that will pay for software. For those people even weak protection will do 95% plus of the job.